# How to ignore some objects in JSON parsed back data?

Tags: json, swiftui, combine

For an instance as below example JSON data, I want to keep the object which has content & video property, and ignore the ones doesn't have them. Objects like 2nd, 3rd with only address and error property should be ignored.

**/ / JSON data example**

```
[
  {
    "content": "asdhh",
    "url": "dasddd",
    "country": "kkjkkj",
    "address": "aksjdkasjd"
  },
  {
    "address": "aabbccdd"
  },
  {
    "error": "error description"
  }
]
```

I try to use `if video.content != nil && video.url != nil` to control the displaying of VideoListRow in ForEach loop. But it turns out that I couldn't call the video.property in the ForEach closure. So how could I ignore the unwanted parsed back data and only show the wanted object, in this case only the first object was wanted.

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.model.videos) { video in
                if video.content != nil && video.url != nil {
                  VStack(spacing: 0) {
                      VideoListRow(video: url)
                  }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            self.model.getVideoBundle()
        }
    }
```

**// Change my code to add filter:**
The minor modification is to use `||` but not `&&`. Because I want to keep the object, which has only one of content and url, that one is valid. Only if it doesn't include two of them, then ignore it.

```
ForEach(
    self.model.videos.filter { (video) -> Bool in
        video.content != nil || video.url != nil
    }
) { video in
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        VideoListRow(video: url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter the data first!

```
ForEach(
    self.model.videos.filter { (video) -> Bool in
        video.content != nil && video.url != nil
    }
) { video in
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        VideoListRow(video: url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you. Actually this filter is a new method in Combine ```Republishes all elements that match a provided closure.```, and I get it now.